# MySQL result dividers

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have dividers in mysql, ie.

```
july
---------------------------------------------
row result
---------------------------------------------
august
---------------------------------------------
row result
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing you should deal with in your application layer.

Comment: Up to a point you could have group by WITH ROLLUP